# Serious installation problems

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop installer, extracted it and ran the wubi.exe as an administrator. An error window opened, saying: "The version of this file is not compatible with your Windows version."

The same error occurs when running directly from the ISO file.

I have Windows 7, 64 bit, with 8gb ram and I tried both the 32- and 64bit versions of Ubuntu. When I installed Ubuntu from the same files on my Windows XP PC, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Put the **iso** on a **cd/usb** (There should be a utility for putting it on a cd on windows) and boot from it (Don't forget to change your bios so you can do that first!), when you have gotten into ubuntu run the setup and when it asks you select where to
install ubuntu, select **install ubuntu alogside windows**! Then just install ubuntu like any other os.
**Downside?** It's a little harder to remove ubuntu but it's still possible.

Comment: I am new to BIOS settings. I googled it and learned how to access the settings, but I don't know what to do there.

Comment: Go to the boot settings (or whatever its called for you) and set the boot order to Usb, (or cd if ur using that) Harddrive, and everything else below. Save and reboot, make sure ur usb/cd is plugged in and boot to ubuntu!

Comment: I set the boot order to usb>harddrive, saved and booted. Windows booted normally, and the same error occurred while trying to install ubuntu.

Comment: huh. Are you on a uefi? In that case remove secure boot and enable legacy boot. Otherwise try again, you might have forgotten to save.